# NGINX location rewrite for WP permalink

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

So, I have WP with almost classic permalink structure, like:      **/%category%/%year%/%month%/%day%/%postname%/**

I would like to redirect with 301 error code to new style, like **/%year%/%month%/%day%/%postname%/** or simple **/%postname%/**.

I've made this rule, but they return same URL.

```
location ~ "^\/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)\/([0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)\/$" {
     rewrite ^(.*) $1 permanent;
 }
```

Or, for /%postname%/ I've tried code like this:

```
location ~ "^\/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)\/([0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)\/$" {
     rewrite ^(.*) $5 permanent;
 }
```

But this code return empty response.

Please, help me solve the issue. I can't catch were I'm wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it was very simple:

```
location ~ "^/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$" {
     rewrite ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /$5/ permanent;
 }
```

This rule rewrite **/category/year/month/day/postname/** to **/postname/** URL in WP with 301 error code for search engines.